# Cache issue with root page for Website configuration

Tags: web, google-cloud-storage

I did setup a bucket as a website however I have some cache issue with the root page.

My setup was done using the following command:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://milomedy.tekartik.com
```

However sometimes the root page does not refresh at all, i.e. the pages http://milomedy.tekartik.com and http://milomedy.tekartik.com/index.html are not the same.

Looking at the headers when this happens we can see that indeed loading both page (even by forcing refresh) won't lead to the same results

```
http://milomedy.tekartik.com

Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Content-Length:68992
Date:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 14:49:18 GMT
ETag:"63807b3debfe4bae2dee7f7f1d6f6c8f"
Expires:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:49:18 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 04 Sep 2014 12:43:02 GMT
```

vs

```
http://milomedy.tekartik.com/index.html

Cache-Control:public, max-age=3600
Content-Length:69125
Date:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 14:58:49 GMT
ETag:"1c77b0b86e70037e1603396022c5b904"
Expires:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 15:58:49 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 14:50:23 GMT
```

Other files (js, css) are loaded fine but since the html loaded is not in synced with the loaded js, it fails. Things seems to get fixed after some period. However I did encounter this long enough (10 mn?) where forcing a refresh on the browser did not update the file to have such solution not viable for a website (I never got this issue using Amazon S3)

In general, I understood that there is a delay when copying files and having them updated using the website configuration url. Copying all the files is not a transaction so there is a risk of having leftover of a V1 version pushed when a new V2 version is pushed. What is the way to workaround this issue and somehow "trigger" a "force refresh on all pages in a directory" so that at least the user pressing F5 could get a working webapp?

Comment: It looks like you're setting the Cache-Control header?

Comment: The cache control is the default from Google Cloud Storage (1 hour). I'm fine with that. However disabling cache on the browser (or forcing refresh) still load sometimes a different version for the root and root/index.html

Comment: If you have Cache-Control set, that means the object can be cached anywhere in the network between you and the server. Since those are two different URLs, they are not necessarily updated in the cache atomically.